# Sharing local variable between nested functions in python

Tags: python, local-variables

How do I get this code to work?

```
def f1():
    def f2():
        print g
        g = 1
        print g
    g = 0
    print g
    f2()
    print g

f1()
```

The expected result is of course 0, 0, 1, 1, printed line by line

Comment: I assume by your `print` statements, you're using Python 2. In Python 3, you can use the `nonlocal` keyword to get what you want. In Python 2, you're pretty much out of luck AFAIK.

Comment: Yes, I use python 2.7.3, but still need to solve a similar situation

Comment: What is your output from this code?

Comment: Why don't you consider putting all this logic into a class? Then you can have `g` as a member of the class to be used anywhere you want.

Comment: NameError: global name 'g' is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use globals:

```
def f1():
    def f2():
        print g[0]
        g[0] = 1
        print g[0]
    g =[0]
    print g[0]
    f2()
    print g[0]

    f1()
```

This is to get around the problem of not being able to reassign a variable belonging to the outer scope. When you reassign it you basically create a new variable within the nested function. To get around that, you wrap your value in a list and reassign the list's element instead.

This is a problem in python 2. Python 3 fixes it through the use of the nonlocal statement:

http://technotroph.wordpress.com/2012/10/01/python-closures-and-the-python-2-7-nonlocal-solution/

Answer (score 0):

What about this :

```
def f1():
    def f2():
        global g
        print g
        g = 1
        print g
    global g
    g = 0
    print g
    f2()
    print g

f1()
```

Output :

```
0
0
1
1
```

Comment: This is basically how it works now, but since I'm running in multithreaded application I prefer to avoid global variables. Why can't python look up the stack for variables?